# Oracle Between dates vs Microsoft Between dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting correct result when I query from Microsoft Query but when I query from SQLPLUS(Oracle) I get incorrect result.

Here is Microsoft Query (Result shows correct from June 12th 3 PM to June 13 12 AM.

```
SELECT 
      NAME,
      CIM,
      NUM_of_People,
      STARTDATETIME
From Table
WHERE (SUSTAINED_FLAG=1) 
AND (PLANNED_FLAG=0) 
AND (STARTDATETIME>{ts '2013-06-12 04:00:00'} 
And STARTDATETIME<{ts '2013-06-13 12:00:00'})
```

In Oracle I am using this clause which gives me wrong result.
 it is showing
query result from dates only after June 13 12:AM to 12 PM.

```
SELECT 
        NAME,
        CIM,
        NUM_of_People,
        TO_CHAR(STARTDATETIME,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') As STARTDATETIME
FROM OBVWH.  
where  BETWEEN To_Date(to_char(STARTDATETIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) >= To_Date('06/12/2013 16:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
and To_Date(to_char(STARTDATETIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) <= To_Date('06/13/2013 12:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
and sustained_flag = 1 and planned_flag = 0 ORDER BY STARTDATETIME ASC
```

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment as I was working on putting it into an answer.

Comment: I deleted mine too, Thanks for help.

Comment: Note that you have "04:00" in the first version, where you have "16:00" in the second. Also the comparison operators switch from `>` and `<` to `>=` and `<=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are having this problem is because of this in the where clause

```
To_Date(to_char(STARTDATETIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
```

What that is doing is stripping the time element from your date so they are all effectively at midnight. A quick example of this would be with

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) = SYSDATE THEN
        'yes'
       ELSE
        'no'
   END
FROM   dual
```

As you can see sysdate is no longer equal to itself after changing the format of it twice.

Since the column is a date you do not have to do any formatting on it at all, just change your where clause to

```
where  STARTDATETIME >= To_Date('06/12/2013 16:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
and    STARTDATETIME <= To_Date('06/13/2013 12:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
and sustained_flag = 1 and planned_flag = 0 ORDER BY STARTDATETIME ASC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation, but I may be wrong, should there be something before `between`?

Comment: it worked fine but there should no `between` after `Where`. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mowgli You can use BETWEEN in this way. `where STARTDATETIME between To_Date('06/12/2013 16:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
and To_Date('06/13/2013 12:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`